# Отслеживание ошибок в node.js

Tags: node.js

Есть запрос в бд:

```
connection.query('INSERT INTO products SET ?', queryObject, function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) {
        throw error;
    } else {
        console.log('SUCCESS: ' + i);
    }        

});
```

Мне необходимо отслеживать ошибку `ER_DUP_ENTRY`, при ней ничего не делать:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все остальные ошибки мне необходимо так же показывать через throw.

Вопрос - как это сделать?

Логика проекта (парсера) такова - ежедневно отслеживаем изменения на сайте доноре, проходясь по всем товарам на сайте, если товар уже есть в БД, то ничего не делаем. Если же нет - добавляем. т.е. ошибка `ER_DUP_ENTRY` покажет, что такой товар уже есть в БД. Если подскажете более адекватный подход, чем отслеживание ошибок - буду признателен.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вместо парса ошибки ER_DUP_ENTRY достаточно воспользоваться INSERT IGNORE для пропуска строки если строка с таким ключом уже есть, либо ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE для обновления уже существующей с таким ключом строки. **Примеры** запросов:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `products`
(`id`,`name`)
VALUES (2, 'Тележка XCD-23');
```

Такой запрос добавит в таблицу тележку, но если уже есть id=2, то ничего не будет.

```
INSERT INTO `products`
(`id`, `name`, `update_time`)
VALUES (2, 'Тележка XCD-23', 1508782806)
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE `update_time`= 1508782806
```

Такой запрос, как не сложно догадаться, добавит тележку, но если уже есть id=2, то обновит поле update_time

Подробнее про INSERT запросы: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

#### UPD

Такого вида запросы будут повышать AUTO_INCREMENT для innodb таблиц. Чтобы этого избежать в конфиге MySQL (у меня он расположен в /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf) добавьте следующую строку:

```
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=0
```

Подробнее про эту настройку: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html

Comment: Большое спасибо!)